# Disable Flurry Analytics (Android)

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

We are going to add an option to our apps to let the users from opting-out sending data to 3rd party analytics tools. We're also using Flurry Analytics to collect some data from users, but after searching in the documentation I was unable to find anything regarding to it.

Is it possible to disable Flurry Analytics after it has been initialized? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once Flurry is initialized, it can't be stopped mid session.

Answer (score 0):

If users opt-out, then do not call `FlurryAgent.Builder.build()`. You will get warning from adb-logcat. But Flurry will not send any data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that's not I'm asking. First, we initialize the SDK after user passes our privacy policy screen. Then, in the app itself, there is a privacy section that users can opt-out **while the app is still open and Flurry was already initialized.** I'm asking about that.